# After using search, a deleted item keeps reappearing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

can anyone help me with my problem. the problem here is after using search and then try to delete an item, the deleted item, reappears
Fragment class:

```
public class DataFragment extends Fragment  implements RecyclerAdapter.OnItemDeleteClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

searchHx = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchHx);
        searchHx.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
private void filter(String text) {
        //filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        filteredList.clear();
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        for (ListSoil item: soilList) {
            if (item.getSoilName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        recyclerAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }
@Override
    public void onItemDeleteClick(int position) {
        soilList.remove(position);
        filteredList.remove(position);
        recyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Adapter class:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    public interface OnItemDeleteClickListener {
        void onItemDeleteClick(int position);
    }
    OnItemDeleteClickListener onItemDeleteClickListener;
    public void setOnItemDeleteClickListener(OnItemDeleteClickListener listener) {
        this.onItemDeleteClickListener = listener;

    }
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    deleteBuilder.setTitle("Alert")
                            .setMessage("Do you want to delete this?")
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    soilList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());

                                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && onItemDeleteClickListener != null) {
                                        onItemDeleteClickListener.onItemDeleteClick(position);
                                    }
                                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
            });
```

I already post a question here, and someone said to use interface with RecyclerAdapter and remove it from the list of Fragment class. I thought deleting both filtered list and the original list would fix the problem, but the deleted item is still there

Comment: The item's adapter position which is based on the _filtered_ data is not the same as the item's position in _unfiltered_ data.  This results to removing the wrong item an the _unfiltered_ data causing the should be deleted item to re-appear when submitting new _filtered_ data to the adapter.